# Putting header in output and raonding numbers

Tags: r

my number in output look like this:

```
[1] 4.032134 1.000000 2.000000
[1] 3.476687 1.000000 3.000000
[1] 2.710619 1.000000 4.000000
```

first I want to round numbers in second and third column(without zeros): 1,2,3
and second I want to have header for each column. generally I want to have suche an output:

```
  Distance  First  second
[1] 4.032134  1      2
[1] 3.476687  1      3
[1] 2.710619  1      4
```

does it possible to do it in R? How can I do that?

**UPDATE**

I am generating this output so:

```
while(i < end-start+1)
{ 
  n<-1
  m<-strsplit(datalist[i],split=",")
  m<-sapply(m,as.numeric)
  m<-c(m)
  while(i+n<=end-start+1)
  {
    k<-strsplit(datalist[i+n],split=",")
    k<-sapply(k,as.numeric)
    k<-c(k)
    alignment<-dtw(k,m)
    output<-c(alignment$distance,round(i,digits=1),i+n)
    print(output)

    n<-n+1
  }

  i<-i+1
}
```

Comment: It is certainly possible. Please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example for ways to improve your question, which is so basic that should be found in any R textbook. Anyway start by giving the type of your variable. Is is a data frame ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This example works for your small dataset. It is probably not the most elegant but it works.

Make a vector of your data

```
DataSet<-c(4.032134,1.000000,2.000000,3.476687,1.000000,3.000000,2.710619,1.000000,4.000000)
```

Transform to a matrix with 3 columns and three rows, sorted by rows
`DataMatrix<-matrix(DataSet, byrow=T, ncol=3)`

The names of your columns according to question
`Names <- c("Distance", "First", "second")`

Here is the crux, use the command colnames(x), and you are done
`colnames(DataMatrix) <- Names`

Printout on screen
`DataMatrix`